# Object removal with filter method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to remove objects with javascript with the filter method. how can i do this.

objects:

**Code:**

```
let todos = [
      {
        id: 0,
        title: "Javascript",
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "php",
        completed: true
      }
]
```

**This method:**

```
function removeElement(id) {
  let checkRemove = confirm("are you sure");
  if (checkRemove) {
    let item = todos.find(item => item.id === id);
    let index = todos.indexOf(item);
    // todos.splice(index, 1);
    let filtered = todos.filter(function(){

    });
    render();
  }
  return;
}
```

I took care of the problem using the following codes thank you

**I solved the problem**

```
function removeElement(id) {
  let checkRemove = confirm("are you sore");
  if (checkRemove) {
    let item = todos.find(item => item.id === id);
    todos = todos.filter(function(item) {
      return item.id !== id;
    });
    console.log(todos);
    render();
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: you'll need some code in the filter callback ... `.filter(item => item.id === id)` perhaps? i.e. exactly the same code you used to find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const removeElement = (id) => confirm('are you sure') ? todos = todos.filter(item => item.id !== id) : todos;

let todos = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: "Javascript",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "php",
    completed: true
  }
];

console.log(todos);
console.log(removeElement(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

**This should work:**

```
function removeElement(id) {
    let checkRemove = confirm("are you sure");
    if (checkRemove){
        //It return all other elements  except the id you pass to removeElement Function
        let filtered = todos.filter(item => item.id !== id);

        render();
    }
    return;
}
```